# Mercury Adventure

Tags: destiny-2

I'm trying to play the first adventure, Bug in the System, from Expansion I: Curse of Osiris on Destiny 2.

It will not allow me access and keeps saying not all members of my fireteam have reached this milestone. I am the Fireteam leader and have nobody in my fireteam.

How do fix this?

Comment: Is it the heroic version or normal version? All normal versions have to be completed before you can do any heroics. Also you might need to talk to the location vendor (Brother Vance?) to begin.

Comment: I've visited him already. It does say heroic but never gave me a normal version option.

Comment: I think this week is the flashpoint on Mercury. So the heroic adventure you see is the planetary daily heroic for the flashpoint meaning its a much higher power level than usual.

Answer (score 2):

To unlock heroic adventures for Curse of Osiris first you'll have to complete the main game campaign and CoO DLC campaign. Once done you'll need to return to Brother Vance and you'll unlock the regular adventures, after completing all of those return once again and you'll be able to access heroic adventures.

Comment: Normal adventures here should be Power level 250.